# usage issues with AquaFX in a java project

Tags: java, javafx, jar

I have started exploring javaFX, and came to know about aquaFX, I downloaded it and added it to my project as referenced libraries, but I don't know how to use aquafx in my project, I'm just trying to develop a basic UI for a desktop application.

Please explain how to use aquafx in my project, I know about UI elements and UIcontrol of javafx, but I can't understand how can I use aquafx with them.

I'm currently using eclipse oxygen 3A.

thanks

Comment: did you try to read [documentation](http://aquafx-project.com/documentation.html) ?

Comment: Thanks for it didn't knew there was one, the git project doesn't include documentation